# Not able to call an action listener for a radio button

Tags: java, swing

[image]I am writing a code where there is a tabbedpane containing 4 tabs. Each tab is containing some radio buttons and a button. the button should act according the pressed radio button. Following is my code for it.

```
       if(radiobtn1.isSelected()==true)
  `                  {
                      System.out.println("option 1 selected");
                  radiobtn1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                            Button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                            // action for radio button 1

                            }
                        }); 


                    }

                    });
              }
              else if(radiobtn2.isSelected()==true){
               System.out.println("option 2 selected");
              radiobtn2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                            Button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                            // action for radio button 2

                            }
                        }); 


                    }

                    });
              }
              }
```

But whenever I am pressing a radio button its action listener is not getting called. Is there anything wrong in my code?

Comment: MIssing other important part of code. We can't understand what you are doing. It seems that you attached actionListener too late, attach them as soon as buttons are created.

Comment: I have edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your code as below

```
rdbtnSample.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                if (rdbtnSample.isSelected())
                    System.out.println("Button Pressed");
                else
                    System.out.println("Button Released");
            }
        });
```

add the if condition inside the action performed.
By default radio button will be deselected.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use the data or the switch parameters to control the action content. Not by the dynamic control the action listener in the buttons.

Just like use the 
int radioButtonIndexPressed = 0;

and in the button press action , use the  radioButtonIndexPressed to decide the real action.